# set the currentTime in HTML5 audio not working properly

Tags: javascript, python, django, http, html5-audio

I built a Music Player in my project and everything works fine.
but in some mp3 files I can't set `currentTime` of Audio element.
for exmaple in this code:

```
src = "music path";
const audioElement = new Audio(src);
let playPromise = audioElement.play();
if (playPromise!==undefined){
    playPromise.then(function() {
        // promised audio started
        audioElement.currentTime = 20;
        console.log(audioElement.currentTime);

        }).catch(function(error) {
        // promised audio failed
    });
}
```

**Program Result =>** `0`
when I'm setting the new currentTime, The audio starts from the beginning and time goes to **zero**.
Audio file is safe and its duration is 120 seconds, so this issue is not for lack of audio duration.
I googled a bit about this problem and realized that some settings should be made in the **Http Headers**. Actually I don't know what is this at all! but I figured that I need to set this settings properly:

```
accept-ranges: bytes

Content-Length: BYTE_LENGTH_OF_YOUR_FILE

Content-Range: bytes 0-BYTE_LENGTH_OF_YOUR_FILE/BYTE_LENGTH_OF_YOUR_FILE

content-type: audio/mp3
```

**UPDATE** > **SOLUTION** 
Finally, after days, I solved this problem and I also realized that it is a very common problem among Django framework users.
All we need is to first send our music file to the client via `FileResponse` and also make some settings in the **HTTP headers** section.

```
from django.http import FileResponse

response = FileResponse(Object.mp3)
response["Content-Disposition"] = f"filename={Object.name}.mp3"
response["Content-Type"] = "audio/mp3"
response["Content-Length"] = os.path.getsize(Object.mp3.path)
response["Accept-Ranges"] = "bytes"
return response
```

**Don't** forget `Accept-Ranges` and `Content-Length` Setting. They are very Important!

Comment: make sure `'music path'` is a URL

Comment: it is  bro, some music's works fine and others not working.

Answer (score 1):

The header of an audio file is like a preface or introduction to it, it lists informations such as the length of the audio file, it's format, encoding method (used to reduce file size) and other data that is needed to play it.

You can modify pretty easily audio files and their associated header with an audio editing software (Audacity for example).

As for your code, you could maybe use .addEventListener to add an event to your audioElement const with the 'canplay' event, which is triggered if and when an audio file can be played on the browser.

For example:
audioElement.addEventListener('canplay', function() {[your code here]}

Comment: I just used canplay but did not solve my issue. still cant set Current Time Properly.

Comment: Maybe the event "loadedmetadata" instead of canplay would work, it verifies that the metadata is loaded before triggering, which could help if your the problem stems from the code trying to set the currentTime before a file is completely loaded.